# Formulario Access dependiente de una Query

Tags: ms-access

Tengo un formulario que se alimenta con una consulta a tres tablas:

[image: Estructura de la consulta]

La consulta tiene esta estructura:

```
SELECT Gastos.Fecha, Gastos.Importe, Gastos.Fichero, Gastos.Fichero.FileName, Gastos.Papel, Proveedores.Nombre, Categorías.Categoría, Categorías.Subcategoría 
FROM Proveedores INNER JOIN (Categorías INNER JOIN Gastos ON Categorías.Id = Gastos.Categoría) ON Proveedores.Id = Gastos.Proveedor;
```

Como resultado de dicha consulta, Access puede crear una tabla con los datos:

[image: Formulario]

Sin embargo, cuando abro el formulario que se alimenta con la consulta, no tiene registros, siendo
su única opción la introducción de un nuevo registro:

[image: Tabla con los datos]

¿Alguien podría ayudarme? Muchas, muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes configurado el origen de datos del formulario? También debes mirar si el formulario está configurado como solo "Entrada de datos" o alguna otra propiedad. Las puedes ver todas en Vista Diseño